# Centering Text in a Flex Column Horizontally

Tags: html, css, web

I’m currently learning how to code a hamburger menu. I would like to have it aligned in the center in a designated  column in a row, and I’m trying to do the same with the links in navigation. However, I can’t get the links to center properly. Below is the code that I have so far:

```css
.grid-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas: "header menu";
     grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    grid-column: span 7;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: black;
}

.nav-test {
     display: flex;
     direction: row;
     justify-content: space-around;
     list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-test a {
    color: white;
 }

.menu {
    display: flex;
    grid-area: menu;
    grid-column: span 1;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item header">
    <ul class="nav-test">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item menu"></div>
</div>
```

My goal is to do the same with the hamburger menu in the last column as well. What is it I’m forgetting to set in order to center the header properly?

Comment: What exactly do you want. It is not so clear. Please be accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default add left padding to a `ul` element, which is pushing the contents of your `nav-test` list over.

The simplest solution would be to reset the padding:

```
.nav-test {
   padding-left:0px; /* add this */
   display: flex;
   direction: row;
   justify-content: space-around;
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go and inspect the nav-test container you'll see that there's an extra 40px padding on the left of the container. This is the reason that your links aren't centered. To fix this just add `padding-left: 0;` in your nav-test class. Try running the snippet and see if this fixes things for you.

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "header menu";
   grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.header {
   grid-area: header;
   grid-column: span 7;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: black;
}

.nav-test {
   display: flex;
   direction: row;
   justify-content: space-around;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-test a {
   color: white;
 }
.menu {
   display: flex;
   grid-area: menu;
   grid-column: span 1;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="menu_design.css">

    <head>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="item header">
                <ul class="nav-test">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item menu"></div>
        </div>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your Nav has some `li` tags which is inside parent tag `ul` so what you can do is in your parent element set `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-around;`  or `justify-content: space-between;` to center each element in your nav-bar

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "header menu";
   grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.header {
   grid-area: header;
   grid-column: span 7;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: black;
}

.nav-test {
   display: flex;
   direction: row;
   justify-content: space-around;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-test a {
   color: white;
 }
.menu {
   display: flex;
   grid-area: menu;
   grid-column: span 1;
   margin: 2px;
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="menu_design.css">

    <head>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="item header">
                <ul class="nav-test">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item menu"></div>
        </div>
    </head>
</html>
```